# Php dropdown menu displaying data via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've installed the MySQL database using the script as in http://www.databasejournal.com/scripts/practice-sql.html :

Then I have my PHP code learnt from Youtube video about how to populate dropdown with data from SQL, but It still can't work that nothing turns out when clicking the "Show details" submit button. I am still new to PHP and can't sort it out myself.  Thank you !!

// PHP Code

```
<?php 
require'require.php';

$usersQuery="
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.cno,
        c.cname,
        o.eno,
        o.shipped
    FROM customers c
    RIGHT JOIN orders o
    ON c.cno=o.cno
    group by (c.cname)

    ";


    $users=$db->query($usersQuery);

    if(isset($_GET['user'])){
        $userQuery="
            {$usersQuery}
            WHERE c.cno=:cno";

        $user= $db->prepare($userQuery);
        $user->execute(['cno'=>$_GET['user']]);
        $selectedUser=$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Dropbox</title>
<script language=JavaScript>

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>My Dropdown</h3>

<form action="dropbox.php" method="get">
    <select name="user">
        <option value="">Choose one</option>
    <?php  foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $user['cno'];?>" <?php echo isset($selectedUser)&& $selectedUser['cno']==$user['cno']? "selected":""?> > <?php echo $user['cname'];?> </option>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</select>

<input type="submit" value="Show details" >
</form>
<?php if(isset($selectedUser)):?>
    <pre><?php echo($selectedUser['cno']);?></pre>
    <?php endif; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't `require` require something? Also DISTINCT and GROUP BY never look good together. You have no aggregating functions so GROUP BY is not required. Finally, RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare. I wonder if there's a reason for that.

Comment: Hi, @Strawberry, Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I wrongly put the DISTINCT in there, and I use GROUP BY to eliminate the replicated data (Just want to make sure distinct names displayed in the dropdown menu). Plus, The reason I use "RIGHT JOINS" was from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5rfX9utf5M. But Why would you not use RIGHT JOIN/LEFT JOIN ? I am still new to all these..;) Thanks !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a code that works.

**I tried to commented all the modifications i made from ur code**

But first let's look into the query u made :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cno, c.cname, o.eno, o.shipped
FROM customers c
RIGHT JOIN orders o
ON c.cno=o.cno
 group by (c.cname)
```

> DISTINCT and GROUP BY @strawberry said doesn't like to be in same query.
>   IN this query the GROUP BY clause "will merge" the result of the query BY cname.

**ORIGINAL :**

> But let's suppose we entered 2 clients with the same name (it's possible coz PRIMARY KEY is cdo) and both of these clients ordered something. U'll miss one by using GROUP BY on a column that isn't a PRIMARY KEY.
>
> BEST way to GROUP BY was on PRIMARY KEY.
>
> Btw Ur variables names can be tricky (like $users & $user)

```
Original queries variables :

$usersQuery =  "SELECT c.cno, c.cname
            FROM customers c, orders o
            WHERE c.cno = o.cno
            GROUP BY c.cno";
AND

$userQuery = "SELECT *
                  FROM customers
                  WHERE cno = :cno";
```

---

**EDIT  :** see Strawberry's comment (below)

**GROUP BY VS DISTINCT**

> I was mistaking about how to build query so i made changes in this way. A better process (for the mind) is running with this query :

```
"SELECT DISTINCT c.cno, c.cname, c.street, c.zip, c.phone
            FROM orders o
            LEFT JOIN customers c
            ON o.cno = c.cno"

Then add a WHERE clause when one user is returned by the form :
```

.

```
<?php 

// My include of connecting to my DB - same as ur require.php i suppose 
include("./inc.connect.php");


// As said before 
$usersQuery =  "SELECT DISTINCT c.cno, c.cname, c.street, c.zip, c.phone
                FROM orders o
                LEFT JOIN customers c
                ON o.cno = c.cno";

$users = $db->query($usersQuery);

if(isset($_GET['user']))
{
    // This query will return all informations about the user u selected
    // $userQuery="{$usersQuery} WHERE c.cno=:cno"
    // as @saty said u missed ':' but ur string query 
    //  You included 2 clause WHERE 
    // (from usersQuery and the concatenation) 

    $userQuery = "{usersQuery} WHERE cno = :cno";

    $user = $db->prepare($userQuery);
    $user->execute(array(":cno" => $_GET['user']));

    $selectedUser = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Display the array (<pre> tag make it readable)
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($selectedUser);
    print "</pre>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dropbox</title>

        <script>
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>My Dropdown</h3>

        <!-- Nothing important : just changed action value coz 
             of my name's page -->
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <select name="user">
                <!-- Added "Default" value for first option -->
                <option value="Default">Choose one</option>
                <?php  
                // used echo only to display html tags - 
                // make it cleaner to read
                    foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user)
                    {
                    // Can't make the display Better - SRY
                        echo "<option value=\"" . $user['cno'] . "\"";
                        echo (isset($selectedUser) && 
                             ($selectedUser['cno'] == $user['cno'])) 
                             ? "selected" :"";

                        echo ">" . $user['cname'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?> 
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Show details">
        </form>
        <?php 
            if(isset($selectedUser))
                echo "<pre>" . ($selectedUser['cno']) . "</pre>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Oh, YOU are awesome!!! @Falt4rm, It now works just fine. However, I am still confused which part I made was not corret, just check the original video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5rfX9utf5M . I basically follow most of the parts he has done...

Comment: Thanks for this. Yeah, very confusing sometimes, and I have not been up to that level so I prefer a cleaner and simpler way to do that...I actually would prefer the "Derek Banas" channel, which is also quite articulate to me. But when talking about "PHP dropdown via SQL", He has also done some tricky part : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FO9gsTCv9g.  But I've learnt a whole lot from these videos.;)

Comment: I don't think SO should be promoting syntax effectively deprecated in 1992. Also, while GROUP BY has an (irritating) performance advantage over DISTINCT, I again think it's wrong to promote its use in the absence of any aggregating functions. MySQL optimizes this behaviour. Other RDBMSs (rightly?) consider this a bug rather than a feature. Finally, there is no requirement here for more than one query!

Comment: Well. Its my turn to learn :D. Nobody said me it was a mistake to use GROUP BY  in these cases. So thx & Then yeah i agree - no need to do more than 1 query.
Found that : http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/
Do u have a better sources about it (so i can fix my mind). I'm editing the code i provided then.

Comment: It's a 'mistake' only insofar as the returned values of non-aggregated columns not included within the GROUP BY are indeterminate. But even if you include all the columns in the SELECT within the GROUP BY, I still think it's an inappropriate use of GROUP BY - because there are no aggregating functions. But I can't say it's 'wrong' because a) MySQL allows it, and b) it actually performs faster than DISTINCT. However, the issue of indeterminate results can be very confusing (especially for a newbie) which is why I prefer not to promote its use in SO.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem is you execute statement. you forget `:` in it and you have to pass array into it.It would be

```
 $user->execute(array(":cno" =>$_GET['user']));
 $selectedUser=$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Read  [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: True about the array, however the : is only required in the statement, not in the key's of the array given to the execute method.